# How to change my code (hashtable + linked lists) to avoid memory leaks?

Tags: c, linked-list, hashtable

Sorry if the following question seems naive, I'm very new to programming and still struggle with basic concepts.

I have written a code that loads a dictionary (txt file) into a hashtable/linked list data structure, the program compiles and provides expected results, but Valgrind shows memory leaks. All major functions (creation of nodes, population, search, print) work fine, except the destroy function (one used to free memory from the mallocs). Valgrind shows memory leaks.

What am I missing here? How to make my code cleaner?

Thanks for your time! You're awesome!

I know that at least partly the reason is my approach to populating the data structure - I use 2 char* buffers (tmp and tmp1, inside and outside of the loop) to juggle inputs from fscanf into the nodes. I guess during unloading I can use the 'free' function on the outside buffer ("tmp"), but not on the inside buffer ("tmp1").

I tried using 1 buffer (both inside and outside the loops) and 2 buffers initialised statically (char tmp[]). Both methods populate the structure with just 1 word (last in the dictionary).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
```

// define node structure

```
typedef struct node
{
    char* word;
    struct node* next;
}node;
```

// hash size variable and hash function (thanks, K&R)

```
const int hash_elements = 100;

unsigned hash(char *s)
{
    unsigned hashval;
    for (hashval = 0; *s != '\0'; s++)
    hashval = *s + 31 * hashval;
    return hashval % hash_elements;
}
```

// function to add node to beginning of ll

```
int addnode_start (node** head, char* word)
{
    node* new_node = malloc(sizeof(node));
    if (new_node == NULL)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    new_node->word = word;
    new_node->next = *head;
    *head = new_node;
    return 0;
}
```

// function to free allocated memory

```
void destroy (node* hashtable)
{
    if (hashtable == NULL)
    {
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        destroy(hashtable->next);
        free(hashtable);
    }
}
```

// MAIN FUNCTION - puts word strings from txt files into hashtable/linked list data structures

```
int main (int argc, char* argv[])
{
    if (argc < 2)
    {
        printf("Usage: ./stringdll dictionary.txt\n");
        return 1;
    }
```

// make an array for linked lists (hashtable) and allocate memory for heads

```
node* hashtable[hash_elements];
for (int i = 0; i < hash_elements; i++)
{
    hashtable[i] = malloc(sizeof(node));
    if (hashtable[i] == NULL)
    {
        return 1;
    }
}
```

// open dictionary file for reading

```
char* infile = argv[1];
FILE* input = fopen(infile, "r");
if (input == NULL)
{
    printf("File does not exist.\n");
    return 1;
}
```

// define temporary storage for strings

```
char* tmp = malloc(41);
```

// scan file for strings and populate linked lists

```
while(fscanf(input, "%s", tmp) != EOF)
{
    char* tmp1 = malloc(41);
    for (int h = 0; h < hash_elements; h++)
    {
        if (hash(tmp) == h)
        {
            if (hashtable[h]->word == '\0')
            {
                hashtable[h]->word = strcpy(tmp1, tmp);
                hashtable[h]->next = NULL;
            }
            else
            {
                int tmp_0 = addnode_start(&hashtable[h], strcpy(tmp1, tmp));
                if (tmp_0 == 1)
                {
                    return 1;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

// unload dictionary

```
for (int d = 0; d < hash_elements; d++)
{
    destroy (hashtable[d]);
}

return 0;
```

}

I expect Valgrind to show that there were no memory leaks during the work of my program.

Comment: You did not `fclose` your file. You never `free` `tmp` and `tmp1`.

Comment: i dont get the question, valgrind will tell you exactly what you are not releasing - release them.

Comment: you are not freeing the words you store in you hash table.

Comment: Your  array is an array of *nodes*. it could be an array of *pointers* to nodes, pointing to the heads of the chains. (and initialised to NULLs)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issues include

1. Your original initialization of the hash table is questionable:

   > ```
   > for (int i = 0; i < hash_elements; i++)
   > {
   >     hashtable[i] = malloc(sizeof(node));
   >     if (hashtable[i] == NULL)
   >     {
   >         return 1;
   >     }
   > }
   > ```

   You are allocating space for nodes, but you do not populate the nodes with valid data.  This allocation appears to be utterly useless.  It looks like it would be not only easier but also more correct to assign `NULL` to the hashtable elements:

   ```
   for (int i = 0; i < hash_elements; i++) {
       hashtable[i] = NULL;
   }
   ```

   From what I can see of your other code, I think it will even handle that without other changes.
2. It's unclear why you need to allocate space dynamically for `tmp`.  You do not seem to do anything with it that would require dynamic allocation -- no runtime-determined length, no use outside the scope of its declaration, ... -- so it would probably be cleaner and easier to declare it as an ordinary array:

   ```
   char tmp[41];
   ```

   You can use that version of `tmp` in all the same ways you show it being used now, and you don't need to free it.
3. You dynamically allocate space for a copy of the input text, but never free it.  The pointers to those spaces are initially recorded in `tmp1`, and then assigned to the `word` members of your nodes.  You do not need or want to free any value held in `tmp1`, therefore, because you are still using those pointers, but your `destroy()` function can and should free each node's `word` before freeing that node.

Comment: Hi John. Thanks for the input. I've assigned NULL pointers to initialisation of the hashtable and changed the loop argument accordignly (from checking that content == \0 to checking if hashtable[h] == NULL. That works, so thanks.

Comment: However, if I initialise both tmp and tmp as char tmp[41] and char tmp[41] my print function prints all the node contents as having the same value (last word in the dictionary). I actually mentioned that i tried static initialisation and it didnt work.

Comment: @MaximBiryukov, I did not say to declare *both* `tmp` and `tmp1` as ordinary arrays.  My comments in that regard were directed specifically to `tmp`.  Moreover, my third point specifically supposes that `tmp1` is still declared as a pointer, for which you dynamically allocate space (and which pointer value you then assign to your nodes' `word` elements).

Comment: JohnBollinger, sorry for this, I'm new to this so this stuff seems overwhelming. Static init of outside buffer worked. Also as @Osiris mentioned I fclose the file in the end. Valgrind still shows "160 bytes in 10 blocks definitely lost"...

Comment: For reference: my dictionary is just 10 words. Valgrind says my program does 21 allocs and 11 frees.

Comment: @MaximBiryukov, did you follow through on my point 3, which advises you to free each node's `word` (before you free the node itself)?

Comment: Yes, I understand now! That was super useful! @John Bollinger, you are awesome! Thanks!!!

Comment: I'm glad it was helpful, @MaximBiryukov.  If you are satisfied that one or both of the answers adequately addresses your question, then it is conventional to "accept" one of them by clicking on the check mark next to its score.